# How to calculate proportion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working on calculating the proportions of no-showers by each age group. However, I am unsure how to do this with the charts I created (please refer to the image below).

First, I created a dataframe with only no_showers. Then, I grouped by age_group and counted the entries which gave me the # of no-showers across different age groups.

To calculate the proportions, I then counted the total number of entries in each age group (no-shower & non-no-showers).

What code should I use to get proportions by age group (i.e. no-show / total * 100)?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTeKu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instaed your solution in picture agregate mean per groups with comparing column `no_show` - then multiple by `100`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'no_show': ['Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
                   'age_group': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
print (df)
  no_show  age_group
0     Yes          1
1      No          1
2     Yes          2
3     Yes          2
4      No          2

df1 = (df['no_show'].eq('Yes')
                    .groupby(df['age_group'])
                    .mean()
                    .mul(100)
                    .reset_index(name='prop'))
print (df1)
   age_group       prop
0          1  50.000000
1          2  66.666667
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. However, it doesn't give the desired result. Instead, I got a list of 'False' boolean.

Comment: @Jenn - sorry, I have typo - `Ye` instead `Yes`, added sample data to answer.